# Include Authentication to $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, getjson

I am getting json data from api with this code:

```
$.getJSON( '../propertylocator/api/configurations', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.rows, function(i, rows) {
            //var homeLatlng= new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', { 
                'Polyline': new google.maps.LatLng(rows.latitude, rows.longitude), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<strong><a href="detailPage.php?id='+ rows.propertyid +'">'+rows.propertyname+'</a></strong><br/>'+rows.propertyoverview }, this);
        });
});
```

Work fine, but yesterday I has included basic authentication with encrypted password to the web app, how I can include authentication to this code to authenticate when get json api?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: Your question is more than unclear. What kind of authentication did you add? At what layer does the authentication need to be made? Page load? on request?

Comment: It's not duplicate entry I need to know how I can authenticate using $.getJSON mode not with $.ajax with url param, I need to send it a username and password to the request.

Comment: @xzegga `$.getJSON` is just a proxy to `$.ajax` with certain parameters pre-set. See the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11960692/283366) for details on passing credentials